# Pygbag not installing

Tags: python, webassembly, pygbag

I have made a game using pygame and I want to share it on itch.io. I wanted to make it so that people don't have to install so I decided to install pygbag. However it isn't working and I can't find anything on why.

This is what happened in command prompt:

```
C:\Users\charl>pip install pygbag
Collecting pygbag
  Using cached pygbag-0.9.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.4 kB)
Using cached pygbag-0.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 MB)
Installing collected packages: pygbag
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\charl\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\pygbag\\pygbag\\pygbag\\pygbag\\pygbag\\pygbag\\pygbag\\pygbag\\pygbag\\pygbag\\pygbag\\pygbag\\pygbag\\pygbag\\pygbag\\pygbag\\pygbag\\pygbag\\pygbag\\pygbag\\pygbag\\pygbag\\pygbag\\pygbag\\pygbag\\filtering.py'
```

Does anybody know what is going on?